# Bind '.error' class to manually created haml wrapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, simple-form-for

I have next group of controls:

```
.control-group.string.required.user_name
  = f.input_field :name, required: true, class: 'form-control'
  = f.label 'User Name'
  = f.error :name
```

Is there any way to bind '.control-group' to it's child input, so if input is invalid, wrapper will get class ".error" added?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a custom component for that, which looks as follows

```
config.wrappers :perfect_forms, tag: 'div', class: 'control-group', required: true, error_class: 'error' do |b|
  b.use :html5
  b.use :input, class: 'fotm-control', required: true
  b.use :label
  b.use :error, wrap_with: { tag: 'span', class: 'help-inline' }
end
```

Now there is a question, if it's possible to detect type of an input inside this config? Because currently to explicitly set a type of an input, I'm writing "input_html: { type: 'text'}" for needed input, but that would be awesome to handle this case inside a wrapper config. Like if type is 'email' - then insert type 'text'.